# Prevent SQL Injection on Insert, php

Tags: php, sql

Can someone just save my life been reading for a few hours,
I followed this exactly:
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

I got this working with sqli but i was told by the group that this was prome to sql injection so i'm trying to improve my code

Alot of the topics here are on SELECT
When I try this i get a blank page, i still haven't gotten apache to render errors that is a separate issue....

this is php:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table', $DBuser, $DBpswd );

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `sonyCES2013`.`registration`  (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `eMail`, `telephone`, `outlet`, `comfirm`, `boothTour`)  VALUES (
    :id,
    :firstName, 
    :lastName,
    :eMail,
    :telephone,
    :outlet,
    :comfirm,
    :boothTour
    )");


    $stmt->bindParam(':id', NULL);
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstName', $fName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastName',$lName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':eMail', $eMail);
    $stmt->bindParam(':telephone', $telephone);
    $stmt->bindParam(':outlet', $outlet);   
    $stmt->bindParam(':comfirm',$comfirmation);
    $stmt->bindParam(':boothTour', $dateFormatted);

    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Why don't you work on "getting apache to render errors" first, it's difficult to tell what the problem is without any error messages.

Comment: You're not checking for errors, and PDO defaults to non-exception mode for errors, so it'll simply return a boolean FALSE when something blows up. YOu need to check the return values of ALL those calls (`$dbh->prepare`, `new PDO`, `$stmt->bindParam`, etc...) for boolean false. ESPECIALLY the initial connection and prepare call. If the prepare succeeds you can usually get away with NOT checking the individual bindParam calls.

Comment: @Mansfield I misinterpreted the question then, my bad. Need another double espresso. (comment deleted)

Comment: Also, a blank page is the result when you don't output anything.

Comment: i changed the php.ini file display errors yes, i dontknow what else i could do....

and yes Mansfiled you are right i did it in sqli and it worked i switched it to PDO and i don tknow why it doesn't work. I will try to get apache to render errors then if this isn't enough info

Comment: might be an issue with the NULL value for ID and the way it's bound

Comment: Man, you did your homework and implemented what indeed prevents SQL injection. The next choice would be to escape whatever strings you pass as part of your SQL. However,  what you are doing is superior.

Comment: @artSir **Double/triple check** all your inputs, form elements, DB fields, DB attributes etc. from `A to Triple ZZZ` - check for letter case/spelling especially. `var_dump()` also

Comment: these inputs work with sqli that is why i dont think is that, and removing id and null didn't work. I gotta get apache to render errors it will make my life easier

Comment: @Mansfield: sending null into an auto_increment field is perfectly acceptable. mysql will intercept the null and replace it with the auto_increment value.

Comment: @MarcB Good to know. That said, it isn't *necessary* to do that, is it? One could just omit the id column from the insert, correct?

Comment: @Mansfield: yep. but doing id=null isn't wrong, just different.

Comment: i was taught to do null, i guess if i dont have to i should leave it out. I actualy got the page working , i found the php.ini and had it render all without notices. It redirect to a thank you.php page like its suppose to but it didn't insert anything.

Comment: @artSir - try `var_dump($stmt->ErrorInfo())` after your `execute()`, and see if the database returned an error.

Comment: thank you! i got this, i now hhave something to work with
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } 

I edited this, i was able to solve 1 but what are tehse other errors? is [0] referring to my id? [1] first name [2] last name?

Comment: sorry i just read up in error info, that error string means there is no error... -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty string is not the same as NULL. Also you must pass variables to `bindParam()` by reference.

If you want to pass a NULL as a query parameter, use

```
$stmt->bindValue(':id', NULL);
```

Or you can make a dummy variable and pass that, and give PDO a hint that it's a NULL:

```
$null = null;
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

Or else just omit `id` from the column in your INSERT:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `sonyCES2013`.`registration`  
    (`firstName`, `lastName`, `eMail`, `telephone`, `outlet`, `comfirm`,
     `boothTour`) VALUES  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had set some attributes to NULL. Comfirm was an optional value on the form and if no one selected it, i made the variable NULL. I instead set them to an empty string ''. that solved the problem.